# rsync symlink help

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to setup rsync to work with symlinks.

**Client to Server:**
For example on my client machine I have a symlink, when I sync to server, it syncs the actual file, which is what I want.

**Server to Client:**
On the server, if I update the file and sync from server to client, it's replacing my symlink with the file, this is not what I want.

**Problem:** 
I need the client symlink to remain intact, and rsync to update the actual file on the client instead.

I've been messing around with the options and can't get it right.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

use `rsync` with `-l` to preserve links!

Comment: ...and `-L` or `--copy-links` to copy what the symlink actually points to.

Answer (score 0):

`-l` (`--links`) and `-L` (`--copy-links`) not works to preserve symbolic links (symlinks) on the target, if on the source there are files, not symlinks. It should be option like `-K` (`--keep-dirlinks`), but for file symlinks. And I can't find it too.